# 8/2(2+2) doesn't work in python but 8/2+(2+2) and 8/2*(2+2) do. Why?

Tags: python, math, sum

Trying to understand operands in python.

8/2(2+2) gave the following error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-8949a58e2cfa> in <module>
----> 1 8/2(2 + 2)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.
```

Trying to do this like this then using sum() then as python dictionary then in numpy.

Comment: Because there is no operator between `2` and `(2+2)`.

Comment: `8/2(2 + 2)` first tries to *call* `2(2 + 2)`, trying to treat `2` like a function. But `int` objects are not callable. Hence the error. You meant `8/2*(2 + 2)`

Comment: The better question is... Is the answer 16 or 1?

Comment: That's quite clear, precedence is left to right.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga your first sentence answers my question perfectly thank you.

Comment: Clarification: 8/2(2+2) = 1 (or 4 or 16 depending on your calculator!), 8/2+(2+2) = 8 and 8/2*(2+2) = 16. Totally different questions. Does this mean that there is no way to make 8/2(2+2)  work in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't support implicit multiplication. When Python tries to run `2(2+2)`, it tries to call the numeric literal `2` as a function, passing `2+2` as an argument to it. You need to use `*` between things you want to multiply.

Comment: Well, not to a function with the global variable `2` since `2` isn't a valid identifier, it is still interpreted as an `int` literal

Comment: Good explanation. Better to mention there cannot be a callable named `2`. Or can there?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Does the new wording make that more clear?

Comment: Yep, it's a pedantic point but since we are talking about how the grammar is parsed I feel it is relevant

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator between the `2` and the `(` - human math assumes a multiplication here but a computer does not.

The parser sees 2(...) - which is interpreted as a function with the name `2` and a parameter.

Since there is no default function with that name and there is no `def 2(x)` you get that error message.

Additionally `2` is not a vaild function name in python.

Comment: Well, *python specifically* works this way. Another programming language could support implicit multiplication. I mean, the *computer* doesn't understand any of that at all, it understands machine code

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't work like normal maths. 2(2+2) will not be executed as 2×4. Instead, 2 will be treated as a function, which is not callable (your error message) . To do that, you've to put operator between `2` and `(2+2)`. Try putting a `*` between 2 and (2+2). Your expression would be `8/2*(2+2)`